# Notifications of PowerDNS authoritative server behind dnsdist not working

Tags: powerdns, dnsdist

I have three DNS servers: x.y.z.10 which is configured as supermaster, x.y.z.11 and x.y.z.12 which both are configured as superslaves. On all three machines:

- dnsdist is running on port 53 for (yet to be done) high availability
- pdns is running on port 1054 as authoritative server
- pdns-recursor is running on port 1055 as recursing resolver

Despite following the advice of dnsdist (https://dnsdist.org/advanced/axfr.html), a `sudo pdns_control notify xxx.de` on the master yields the same error on all slaves: `pdns_server[]: Received NOTIFY for xxx.de from 127.0.0.1:39562 which is not a master (Refused)`.

`dnsdist` is configured to pass SOA, AXFR and IXFR requests that originate from the network to pdns and everything else to pdns-recursor:

```
addAction(AndRule({OrRule({QTypeRule(DNSQType.AXFR), QTypeRule(DNSQType.IXFR)}), NotRule(makeRule("x.y.z.0/27"))}), RCodeAction(DNSRCode.REFUSED))
addAction(AndRule({OpcodeRule(DNSOpcode.Notify),NotRule(makeRule("x.y.z.0/24"))}), RCodeAction(DNSRCode.REFUSED))

addAction(OrRule({QTypeRule(DNSQType.SOA), QTypeRule(DNSQType.AXFR), QTypeRule(DNSQType.IXFR)}), PoolAction("primary"))
addAction(AllRule(), PoolAction("recursor"))
```

`pdns` is configured as a (super)slave and to accept AXFR/NOTIFY only from localhost:

```
master = no
slave = yes
superslave = yes
allow-axfr-ips = 127.0.0.1
disable-axfr = no
allow-notify-from = 127.0.0.1
```

What/where did I mess up?

Answer (score 0):

On the slave's database, did you put 127.0.0.1 in the supermaster table, with the hostname of the slave? Ie,

```
INSERT INTO `powerdns`.`supermasters` (`ip`, `nameserver`, `account`) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'dns-02.domain.com', 'admin');
```

If so, I'm curious what else you needed to do to get it working.